# Calculating Percentage in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

Trying to find a percentage of modified items and setting it up in an email alert. In another part of the alert the percentage works fine but this is the line i'm having problems with

```
select CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), 150) + ' (' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,2), ((50) / 150) * 100)) + '%' + ')'
```

It is using existing variables that is why it needs to be converted, I just have random values entered in where the fields would be. 150 being the total items and 50 being the modified items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why "random" values would appear.  I can understand unexpected results.

This expression:

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,2), ((50) / 150) * 100)
```

is more simply written as:

```
0
```

The reason is that SQL Server does integer division.  So, you need to convert the values before you do the division.  I often do this by multiplying by 1.0:

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,2), ((50)*1.0 / 150) * 100)
```

Comment: This worked. Although it is strange because similar calculations are used higher up in the email report, but for some reason it does not convert that values but they seem to be correct.